# Android Gridview not scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, scroll, custom-adapter

I am trying to implement gridview to show my images. I got my codes working to show my images but the problem is the gridview is not scrolling to show my other images. I have 15 images but it only shows 6 image (2 columns). What am I missing here? Below are my codes.

From my Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ates, container, false);
    templateGridContainer = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_templates);

    tAdapter = new TemplatesAdapter(getActivity(), imageIDs);
    templateGridContainer.setAdapter(tAdapter);

    templateGridContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked grid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    return rootView;
}
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
public class TemplatesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ImageView imageView;
private TextView imageTitle;
private Integer[] imageIDs;

public TemplatesAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageSet){
    context = c;
    imageIDs = new Integer[imageSet.length];
    imageIDs = imageSet;
}

//---returns an ImageView view---
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;
        if (convertView == null){
            gridView = new View(context);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_template_layout, null);
            imageView = (ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_temp_img);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            imageTitle = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.textView_temp_title);
        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);

        return imageView;
}

//---returns the number of images---
public int getCount(){
    return imageIDs.length;
}
//---returns the ID of an item---
public Object getItem(int position){
    return position;
}
//---returns the ID of an item---
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}
}
```

My Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mx_gray"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview_templates"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="82"
    android:numColumns="2" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My row layout for custom adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mx_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_temp_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_temp_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/mx_white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

when setting gridview to return

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View  gridView = new View(context);
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_template_layout, null);
    imageView = (ImageView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_temp_img);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

    imageTitle = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.textView_temp_title);

    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
    //            imageTitle.setText(position);
    return gridView;
}
```

Here is the resulting errors:

```
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:655)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:651)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5059)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2385)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15504)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1979)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1222)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1395)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-08 19:29:58.613: E/AndroidRuntime(15784):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue that appears is that, you are not updating your convertView as that should be the one returned in getView. (or the gridView you have created)

Don't know why you are creating a GridView when you already have one in the MainLayout which is your convertView itself.

Do the below changes and it should work:

```
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_template_layout, null); // your convert view should be the one that is assigned the inflate layout

   imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_temp_img);
   imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
   imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

   imageTitle = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.textView_temp_title);        

   imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
```

Then the return statement,

```
    return convertView;// should return your converView
```

Comment: Did you initiate it - convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_template_layout, null); ?

Comment: ok do one thing, rollback to your initial code and just return your gridView there instead of imageView. (this return gridView; instead of this return imageView;)

Comment: It still gives me the classCastException. Can it be because my gridview is in a fragment? Can there be a conflict between gridview inside a fragment.

Comment: Can you post you log cat and the new code you edited?

Comment: Comment this line and try, imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));

Comment: And if in case you want your ImageView to be of 200*200 then assign this values in the xml file as it layout_width and layout_height

Comment: The issue is your ImageView lies in a LinearLayout but via code you are assigning it LayoutParams of a GridView. Hence the ClassCast.

Comment: well it did display my images and the error is gone.. but scroll function is still not working.. i dont know what i missed?

Comment: You sure you have enough images for scroll? You getting any logs now? Mind posting the new code?